# Why is my maintenance plan save overwriting job ownership?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I'm slowly untying all the system dependencies to the previous DBA's system account and moving them to a service account. The old DBA had ownership of all the jobs in our maintenance plan. In SSMS I can change the ownership directly and verify the changes have been applied with this query:

```
USE MSDB
GO
SELECT GETDATE() AS 'ExecutionTime'
GO
SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS 'SQLServerInstance'
GO
SELECT j.[name] AS 'JobName',
Enabled = CASE WHEN j.Enabled = 0 THEN 'No'
ELSE 'Yes'
END,
l.[name] AS 'OwnerName'
FROM MSDB.dbo.sysjobs j
INNER JOIN Master.dbo.syslogins l
ON j.owner_sid = l.sid
ORDER BY j.[name]
GO
```

However when I modify the maintenance plan and save the ownership reverts to the old DBA account. I've combed through the GUI for a reference to his account but I can't find one.

Why is this happening and what I do I need to change to keep the maintenance plan from overwriting Job ownership.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug report on [Microsoft Connect](http://goo.gl/WhaEN). There are workarounds in that link.